# spring boot rest decrement on day from date

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I have a project using spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE andangular 6, from the front i send data to the banckend, the sent json is like this `{ "startDate":"2020-11-10T23:00:00.000Z" }`, when i debug my controller i find that the date is less than the sent date by a day `Tue Nov 10 00:00:00 WAT 2020`

```
public class UpdateSpecialityRequest {

   @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date startDate;

}

@PatchMapping
public ResponseEntity<Void> updateSpeciality(@RequestBody @Valid UpdateSpecialityRequest updateSpecialityRequest) {
    service.updateSpeciality(updateSpecialityRequest);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson:
     serialization:
       write-dates-as-timestamps: false
     time-zone: Europe/Paris
     locale: fr_FR
```

Comment: Your jsonFormat pattern is missing the time part, which is why the time is ignored and date is captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default format

YYYY-MM-DD

So Jackson is formatting the date correctly. If this is not the right behaviour, then pass a format to jackson

You have to fix your JsonFormat annotation

Example

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss")
private Date someDateField;
```